# Delete by create selection like in photoshop for illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to illustrator. I want to delete part of object like what that i can do in photoshop.
In photoshop if i want to delete part of layer, i just create selection(from selection tool or from layer), then delete. How can i delete part of layer like in illustrator from selection that create from object?

Answer (score 1):

Not really appropriate for stackoverflow but...

Moving into Illustrator from Photoshop can be a tough transition. When you're used to the ability of working directly with pixels, a vector based program like Illustrator definitely feels a little bit awkward.

To answer your question, there are a number of ways you can do this. The first is by using the eraser tool. This is very similar to photoshop, you simply select the path in question and erase whatever you don't want.

Another way, which sounds closer to what you may want, is to use one object's path to delete a piece of another path which may or may not be on different layers (Illustrator uses layers a little bit differently than Photoshop). This takes advantage of the `pathfinder` palette. Let's say you have a circle on layer 2, which is above a rectangle on layer 1. If you want to delete the shape of that circle from the rectangle you would first make sure both objects are selected, then navigate to the pathfinder palette and click `Minus Front`. This will use the path of the circle to delete that shape from the rectangle. There are many other options on the pathfinder palette that allow you to do more things like this (intersect, exclude, merge, etc).

If you don't have an existing path (the equivalent of a selection in Photoshop) that you want to delete, all you have to do is draw the path with either the shape tool or the pen tool. Once you have your selection you just follow the steps above.

Here's a visual example of what I mean: http://www.briangervais.com/blog/subtract-from-a-shape-using-illustrators-pathfinder-palette

Answer (score 0):

- Click the eraser icon on the toolbox (usually on the left)
- Hold the ALT key
- Select by clicking and dragging the left mouse button what you want to erase, this will erase everything in the selection.

Quick and easy way of deleting everything by selection.